# SQL script to remove zeros between alphabetic and numeric values within a field

Tags: sql, database, db2

I would like to update a table within my db2 database and remove the zeros that are between the alphabetic and numeric values.

For example I have the column element: CompanyName. I would like to get all the CompanyName's that have the zero(s) between alphabetic and numeric values, i.e. ABCD001234, and replace it with ABCD1234. There are over 30000 of these values, so a script is needed.

Some more examples of the trimming are shown below:

- `ABCD1234 -> ABCD1234 (no change)`
- `JFKD011011 -> JFKD11011`
- `A000000001 -> A1`
- `Z000000000 -> Z0`

Preferably, I would like a script that I can test without the UPDATE, and then add the UPDATE statement after the results look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select                                                    
trim(translate(CompanyName, '          ', '0123456789')) ||        
cast(translate(CompanyName, '                          ', 'ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') as integer)                                               
from yourtable
```

Comment: I get the error `SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token "translate(CompanyName, ' ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO" was found following "23456789')) || case(". Expected tokens may include: "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104`

Comment: i have modified my query with space, try it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column is called COL1, in table TABLE1, you can obtain new values as desidered in NEWSTR.   From there you can easily prepare the UPDATE:

```
SELECT COL1, SUBSTR(COL1, 1, ZX) 
|| CAST( CAST(SUBSTR(COL1, ZX+1,99) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(18)) AS NEWSTR
     FROM 
    (SELECT COL1, LENGTH(COL1) AS ZY, LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(COL1, ' ', '0123456789 ')))   AS ZX FROM TABLE1) X
```

;

To make a test:

```
    SELECT COL1, SUBSTR(COL1, 1, ZX) 
    || CAST( CAST(SUBSTR(COL1, ZX+1,99) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(18)) AS NEWSTR
         FROM 
        (SELECT COL1, LENGTH(COL1) AS ZY, LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(COL1, ' ', '0123456789 ')))   AS ZX FROM 
                   (SELECT 'ABCD1234' AS COL1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL SELECT 'JFKD011011' AS COL1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
      UNION ALL SELECT 'A000000001' AS COL1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL SELECT 'Z000000000' AS COL1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 
      ) K
) X
```

Output:

```
COL1       NEWSTR   
 ---------- ---------
 ABCD1234   ABCD1234
 JFKD011011 JFKD11011
 A000000001 A1
 Z000000000 Z0
```

In MSSQL it should be easier, using PATINDEX() function.

Comment: I get the error `A numeric argument of a built-in string function is out of range.. SQLCIODE=-138`

Comment: I corrected first line ( `...SUBSTR(COL1, 1...`  .  If you still got error, please try to isolate the value(s) casuing it and let me know.